# Why is my Azure Function V2 not logging to app insights?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a very simple function and boiled it down further more to trouble shoot this issue, I read some previous questions on SO about similar issues but they dont apply to my issue I believe.

Function code

```
[FunctionName("XXXItems")]
        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 45 6 * * 1-5")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {

            log.LogInformation($"XXXItems --> Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

}
```

I have configure the APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY in the function settings

But nothing gets logged and I am a bit lost as how to debug this

Comment: Are you changing anything in the logger section of Host.json?

"logger": {
        "categoryFilter": {
            "defaultLevel": "Information",
            "categoryLevels": {
                "Host": "Error",
                "Function": "Error",
                "Host.Aggregator": "Information"
            }
        }
    }

Comment: No changes at all my config is very basic

Comment: to be clear my host.json is totally empty

Comment: Is it happening on all the function app or Is it happening on one function app. Just to isolate more could you try creating the new basic function app and enable Application insight for logging and see if that works.

Comment: Its all of them and this is a new one I created with a new App Insights instance as well

Comment: but should my host.json be empty ? I read you only needed to enter things there if you wanted change things

Comment: ok I created a new function app, copied one function over , loggin works, I copied a second function over logging does not work for the second function but still works for the first function. Both uses the exact same log statement and iLogger